# php: I want to trim "h;" from "w;h;" to get ''w;' but what I got is "w"

Tags: php, trim

The below program is to right trim the string "w;h;" off string "h;" to get "w;". But unexpectedly what I got is "w", not "w;".

```
<?php

        $string="w;h;";
        $str="h;";
        $nStr=rtrim($string,$str);
        echo $nStr.'</br>';

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use str_replace http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$string="w;h;";
$str="h;";
Echo str_replace($str, "", $string);
```

https://3v4l.org/P9Hbe

Str_replace replaces $str with nothing. Leaving `w;`

Answer (score 1):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

> **character_mask**
>
> Optionally, the stripped characters can also be specified using the character_mask parameter. Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped. With .. you can specify a range of characters.

If you do `rtrim("w;h;", "h;")` you're saying "trim either `h` or `;` from the end of the string, meaning cut off characters that are either `h` or `;` in this case it will cut off characters until it is only left with `w`.

If you want to remove a specific string from the end you have to do something like:

```
if (substr($string,-strlen($str)) == $str) {
    $string = substr($string,0,-strlen($str));
}
```

Note: This assumes ASCII strings. For UTF-8 multibyte strings use `mb_substr` .